# How to remove duplicates data from NSArray written with JSONModel?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, duplicates, nsarray, jsonmodel

I use JSONModel to parse json and, convert it to NSArray to use it in `UITableView`.

```
"<RSTweakItem> \n   [name]: WhatAboutThis\n   [version]: 1.2\n   [packageID]: com.peterdev.whatabouthis\n</RSTweakItem>",
"<RSTweakItem> \n   [name]: WhatAboutThis\n   [version]: 1.2.1\n   [packageID]: com.peterdev.whatabouthis\n</RSTweakItem>"
```

this is the part of json data converted to `NSArray` with `JSONModel`.

As you can see, These have the same name and packageID but different version.

So I want to check the `packageID` to make sure it is the same package, then remove the old version of the data and leave only the latest version of the data.

This is how I set `UITableView` with data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RSTweakCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RSTweakCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    RSTweakItem *model = self.listTweak[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = model.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = model.version;
    cell.packageID = model.packageID;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray<RSTweakItem> *models = @[];//parse from json
    NSMutableArray *packageIDs = [[models valueForKey:@"packageID"] mutableCopy];//get all packageIDs
    NSMutableArray *newModels= [NSMutableArray new];//for unique last versions of RSTweakItem
    while (packageIDs.count > 0) {
        NSString *pID = packageIDs.firstObject;
        //get all objects packageIDs equal pID
        NSArray *filteredAray = [models filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.packageID like  %@", pID]];
        if(filteredAray.count  > 0) {
//            sort to get lates version
            NSArray *sorteArray = [filteredAray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(RSTweakItem *obj1, RSTweakItem *obj2) {
                return [obj1.version compare:obj2.version];
            }];
            [newModels addObject:sorteArray.lastObject];
        }
        [packageIDs removeObject:pID];
    }
```

Comment: I’ll check it when I get back from the vacation!

Comment: It's not that fast, but works like charm! thanks :)